# Calling route when no other routes match url with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to redirect non-matching urls to a specific route using React-Router.  For example, if user navigates to `https://www.mysite/com/no-match` and I don't have a corresponding route set up, it should push them to `https://www.mysite/com/home`.

I'm sure there's a way to do this but can't find it in docs.

For any AngularJS folks, this would be equivalent to `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')`

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is a subcomponent of React Router that is perfect for this. You're looking for the Redirect component: [Redirect Docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md).

You can place this as a child to the route that you want to redirect and it should take care of this functionality for you.